# Sorting with MVCContrib

Tags: sorting, mvccontrib-grid

I have 
 public class X
    {
public List ListY { get; set; }
}

public class Y
    {
        public Y();

```
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

I am showing the value of Amount in the grid. How to sort on this column.
Is there a way to access this column to apply sort?

Thanks in advance
Upendra

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you should have something like this:

```
 <%= Html.Grid(Model.PagedList).Columns(col => {
      col.For(l => l.Amount).Named("Amount");
      /* other columns here */
 }).Sort(Model.GridSortOptions) %>
```

In your controller action, you would have something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(GridSortOptions gridSortOptions)
{
        //Code
}
```

You can download a complete MvcContrib Grid sample here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Grid_Paging_In_MVC3.aspx

You will see how you can implement sorting using MvcContrib Grid.